# Two diffident output on Stanford parser

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I parse a sentence "The man swimming in the lake is my father." with deduction "...who is...". "swimming" in this sentence is a verb.

The tree structure shows that "swimming" is a verb.
[image: Tree parsing]

However, in dependency parsing (DP), "swimming" is a noun.

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP
      (NP (DT The) (NN man) (NN swimming))
      (PP (IN in)
        (NP (DT the) (NN lake))))
    (VP (VBZ is)
      (NP (PRP$ my) (NN father)))
    (. .)))

det(swimming-3, The-1)
compound(swimming-3, man-2)
nsubj(father-9, swimming-3)
case(lake-6, in-4)
det(lake-6, the-5)
nmod:in(swimming-3, lake-6)
cop(father-9, is-7)
nmod:poss(father-9, my-8)
root(ROOT-0, father-9)
```

I am confusing about DP output, is it correct?

Comment: `The man swimming` as an NP sure looks wrong to me but dependency parsing is smart enough to know that swimming happens in the lake. But if you just look at the 1st level the full NP `The man swimming in the lake` looks righ tthough.